# Use XSD generated class to deserialize XML in C#?

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

I created a class from a XML file using the xsd tool that comes with the .NET framework. I included it into my solution. The created class contains many classes and since I am new to this topic I wonder which class to use?

```
StreamReader str = new StreamReader(@"c:\t.xml");
XmlSerializer xSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeClassFromCreatedClass));
SomeClassFromCreatedClassexporis = (SomeClassFromCreatedClass)xSerializer.Deserialize(str);
```

Problem is, it says **Error in XML-Document (2,2)** on the 3rd line. So in general, which of the created classes should I use? What could be the problem?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the Xml schema defines many different types (either seperate elements or more likely, nested complex types). Xsd will generate a seperate class for each nested complex type... so you need to ascertain which type is the root of the hierarchy. This would be the type you need to deserialize :)

On a seperate note.. xsd.exe is extremely limited, far better to use something like [Xsd2Code](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/) :)

Comment: Using Xsd2Code did not change anything ... I still get the error. How do I know which is the root of the hierarchy?

Comment: Found the solution, take a look here: http://satov.blogspot.com/2006/12/xsdexe-generated-classes-causing.html

Comment: Your question was "*which of the created classes should I use?*". The solution you linked to is not related to that question. Please be more specific with your questions in the future.

Comment: @grady that is a subscription only blog and not really appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the error reporting of the XML deserializer.

You will find the real error if you drill down all the inner exceptions, which is quite painful.